# Cloning a form dynamically during run-time

Tags: c#

Say I have a form called "FormA" with two textboxes text1_a and text2_a.How can I create a form dynamically during runtime called "FormB" with the same objects that are in FormA having the same layount only with different names for the textboxes such as text1_b and text2_b

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Why not just create two instances of `FormA`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
FormA cloningForm = new FormA();
cloningForm.Show();
cloningForm.Name = "FormB";
cloningForm.text1_a.Name = "text1_b";
cloningForm.text2_a.Name = "text2_b";
```